# Question about laser printer

Tags: print-production, laser

I'm trying to print double side pages with my laser printer, I noticed that when I run my paper 2 times in the printer, the paper becomes kinda grey and not as white as it was... I read online that when the toner is fused on paper the temperature in the fuser assembly is about 427 °C, could it be that reason or my drum is damaged?

I also tried to print dots in one single paper 10 times just to see the results and it became darker the more I print on it.

Comment: For double side prints try an inkjet printer.

Answer (score 5):

**Never** run paper through a laser printer twice unless it is *specifically designed* to do so and has a "duplex" feature.

If your laser printer is not designed to print double-sided (duplex) on its own, all you are doing is damaging the printer which will eventually mean you'll need a new one. **You are damaging the drum when you do this.** The drum is essentially the *entire* machine. And yes, that could account for "greying" in areas... because the drum has had toner fused to it when it shouldn't have *any* toner on it. The fuser heats up an melts the toner on the back side (which shouldn't be there) and it gets transferred to the drum.

Here's a couple screenshots from various manuals for printers *without* the duplex feature.

An HP Manual....

[image]

A Samsung Manual....

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103391/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-question-about-laser-printer).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a printer malfunction where a fine layer of toner is being applied to the print. The temperature should not discolor the paper unless you are running paper that is not suitable for a laser printer. Check the label to make sure. Even if it were a heat-related issue, the color would probably be more yellow or brown from heat. Paper that is lodged in the fuser during a jam is usually singed with yellows and browns. Look at the paper with a loupe or strong magnifying glass. Does the gray consist of dots? Is it happening on both sides of the sheet? Fold the paper over and see in one side is noticeably lighter than the other. A singed sheet will be affected on both sides.